# How to connect the camera from iphone to mac

Tags: iphone

I need to know if there is a way to connect the camera of iPhone to mac. My aim is like to create a spying camera where iPhone will act as the spying device and we will see the view from its camera on mac screen.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for this.  The "answer" is to build a client and then capture the images on the iPhone screen and transmit them to the client server.